# How to create a JMETER setenv.bat file with Environment variables

Tags: jmeter, setenv

I want to create a JMeter setenv.bat that contains environmental variables such as set JMETER_HOME=xx
I want to just type 'jmeter' anywhere on the Terminal CL in any directory to start jmeter, could this done ?

I have used a symbolic link but setenv.bat file must be a better way.

Any example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to launch JMeter from any place you need to add "bin" folder of your JMeter installation to your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

For Windows it can be done via [setx command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) like:

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;c:\jmeter\bin
```

replace `c:\jmeter\bin` with the actual path to your JMeter's bin folder.

In the same shell or after next login you will be able to type `jmeter` and it will run JMeter GUI.

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)